# Swift 3.0 XCTest.performTest(_:) #selector

Tags: selector, swift3

In Swift 2.3 `[XCTest performTest:]` was translated to Swift as `public func performTest(run: XCTestRun)`

In Swift 3.0 it became `open func perform(_ run: XCTestRun)`

With this change I'm stuck trying to get the method selector (even following suggestions https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1016 and https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1033).

```
#selector(XCTest.perform(_:)) -> matches NSObject's performSelector
#selector(XCTest.perform as (XCTestRun) -> Void) -> ambiguous reference to member 'perform'
#selector(XCTest.perform(_:) as (XCTestRun) -> Void) -> cannot convert value of type '(Selector!) -> Unmanaged<AnyObject>!' to type '(XCTestRun) -> Void' in coercion
```

How do I get the `performTest` selector properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, the type of `XCTest.perform(_:)` is curried, so one will need the ugly:

`#selector(XCTest.perform(_:) as (XCTest) -> (XCTestRun) -> Void)`